# A Suitable Replacement for MCrypt?

Tags: encryption, php, openssl

I'm rewriting a legacy PHP web application that makes heavy use of MCrypt. It's on a shared host and handles payment data as well as personally identifiable information.

What is a suitable replacement, if any, besides OpenSSL?

Comment: If by payment data, you mean credit card numbers, you'll need to comply which PCI-DSS, which is a pain. The general recommendation is to never let those touch your server, using a PSP instead that receives the CC number and replaces it by an opaque token before it's sent to your server.

Comment: For the connection itself you must use HTTPS/SSL/TLS. `mcrypt` is mainly for encrypting data at test, but since you need to store the key where it can be accessed by your web application, the practical security gain is rather small.

Answer (score 1):

As per the wikipedia entry:

> "The last update to libmcrypt was in 2007,[1] despite years of
> unmerged patches.[2] These facts have led security experts to declare
> mcrypt abandonware and discourage its use in new development.
> Maintained alternatives include ccrypt, libressl, and others.[3]"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mcrypt

I would also note: php has a `crypt()` call which supports CRYPT_STD_DES, CRYPT_EXT_DES, CRYPT_MD5, CRYPT_BLOWFISH, CRYPT_SHA256, CRYPT_SHA512.

But this function is NOT currently binary safe.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: The `crypt` _function_ in both PHP and Unix is for password hashing, only, and completely different from and unrelated to the (obsolete former) `crypt` _program_.